# Адаптивный шрифт

Tags: css3, html, css, шрифты

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать адаптивным шрифт?

Comment: Адаптивный шрифт - это как?

Comment: когда уменьшается окно браузера или сайт просматривается на телефоне, планшете и т.д. - шрифт соответственно тоже уменьшался и не обрезался.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте адаптивную верстку и задавайте разный размер шрифта для разных размеров экрана
[Немного про `media queries`](http://designnotfound.ru/about-media-queries/)

Comment: мерси за ответы, сейчас постараюсь разобраться)

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать `em` или `rem`, а через  `media queries` уже для разных экранов менять юзовый размер экрана